# Add additional control to ObervableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm really new to WPF so apologies in adavnced if this is an obvious question.  I have a simple Checkbox in XAML as

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Selections}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                       Content="{Binding Path=Item.SelectionName}" />
                    </Grid >  
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Simplified code behind to allow bindings and INotifyPropertyChanged is:

```
public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Selection>> Selections { get; set; }

public class Selection
{
    public String SelectionName { get; set; }
}

  Selections = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Selection>>();
  Selections.Add(new CheckedListItem<Selection>(new Selection() 
         { SelectionName = "SomeName" }, isChecked: true));

    public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool isChecked;
        private T item;

        public CheckedListItem()
        { }

        public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
        {
            this.item = item;
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }

        public T Item
        {
            get { return item; }
            set
            {
                item = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
            }
        }


        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
            }
        }
    }
```

I now need to add an additional TextBox associated with each Checkbox, so in XAML I have

```
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Selections}" Margin="12,22,12,94">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                       Content="{Binding Path=Item.SelectionName}" />
                    <<TextBox />
                    </Grid >  
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I'm a bit stumped how to include this as part of the ObservableCollection and set it up the binding on both the CheckBox and associated TextBox? Both are being added together using `Selections.Add(new CheckedListItem<Selection>(new Selection() 
         { SelectionName = "SomeName" }, isChecked: true));` which is causing me some confusion.

EDIT: Added full code

```
public partial class SelectionSettingWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Selection>> Selections { get; set; }

        public class Selection
        {
            public String SelectionName { get; set; }
            public string SelectionTextField { get; set; }
        }

        public SelectionSettingWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Selections = new ObservableCollection<CheckedListItem<Selection>>();
            string fg = @"Item1,true,TExtbox1text:Item2,true,TExtbox2text:Item3,false,TExtbox3text"; //Test String
            string[] splitSelections = fg.Split(':');
            foreach (string item in splitSelections)
            {
                string[] spSelectionSetting = item.Split(',');

                bool bchecked = bool.Parse(spSelectionSetting[1].ToString());
                string tbText = spSelectionSetting[2].ToString();
                Selections.Add(new CheckedListItem<Selection>(new Selection() 
                   { SelectionName = spSelectionSetting[0].ToString(),   
                       SelectionTextField = bText }, isChecked: bchecked));

            }

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public class CheckedListItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private bool isChecked;
            private T item;
            private string textField;

            public CheckedListItem()
            { }

            public CheckedListItem(T item, bool isChecked = false)
            {
                this.item = item;
                this.isChecked = isChecked;
            }

            public T Item
            {
                get { return item; }
                set
                {
                    item = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
                }
            }


            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return isChecked; }
                set
                {
                    isChecked = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
                }
            }

            public string TextField
            {
                get { return textField; }
                set
                {
                    textField = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TextField"));
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
       ItemsSource="{Binding Selections}" Margin="12,22,12,94">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                   Content="{Binding Path=Item.SelectionName}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Item.SelectionTextField, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>  
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

replace `SelectionTextField` above with whatever the field is that needs to be edited using the textbox on your `Selection` class.

Note that I changed the `<Grid>` to a `<StackPanel>` So they wouldn't appear on top of eachother and changed the bindings to TwoWay so the changes are reflected in the model.

Make sure your `Selection` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (ObservableCollection updates the UI when things get added to/removed from the collection, it doesn't know anything about notifying when it's content's properties change so they need to do that on their own)

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on many classes can be cumbersome. I find implementing a base class useful for this. I've got this along with an extra reflection helper for raise property changed available [here](http://amoore.katalyststudios.com/sites/default/files/Aaron%20Moore%20MVVM%20Foundation.zip) and a [snippet](http://amoore.katalyststudios.com/files/MVVMProperty.snippet) I've made available. It's silverlight but it should work fine for WPF. Using the code I've provided via download you can simply type `proprpc` and hit tab and visual studio will stub in a property that notifies on change. Some explanation is in one of my old blog posts [here](http://amoore.katalyststudios.com/content/game-day) and gives credit for where I based the code and snippet from.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess my question really is do I need 2 ObservableCollections, one for the Checkbox and another for the TextBox?  Item. is part of the CheckedListItem class so wouldn't fire if I changed the TextBox

Comment: Both have the same datacontext - you can bind them to different properties on the same object. I am confused though. you say you have a "simple checkbox" but it's in the listbox, now asking if you need 2 lists (ObservableCollection)? You DO have multiple `CheckedListItem<Selection>` yes? The ItemTemplate is basically a template for each individual `CheckedListItem` in the list. And each `CheckedListItem` has `Item` so simply adding another string property to the class stored in `Item` would work. Make sure `Selection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: I don't think I understand. I've tried adding a property change event for Item.SelectionTextField but it doesn't fire. Also I can't initialise the TextBox with `Selections.Add(new CheckedListItem<Selection>(new Selection() { SelectionName = "SomeName", SelectionTextField = "Initial Text" }, isChecked: true));`

Comment: I've added the more of my codebehind with attempt to implement your suggestions (perhaps not correctly).

Comment: `Selection` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I've updated my answer and provided a couple helpful bits of code via download.